# how to create SearchView in Android 2.3 below version

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to get SearchView in Android 2.3 below version.
But.. Android3.0 supports SearchView.
How can i get SearchView in the below version?
Please Help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/) link will help you. Here there is no need of `searchview`. Just you can achive your requirement with `EditText`. Or otherwise you can use [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) also.